# Как правильно реализовать мультиязычность в React + Redux

Tags: reactjs

Непосредственно из компонента реакта делаю запрос к api.
Ответ приходит на английском языке и выводится на экран.

Хочу сделать приложение с 2 языками русском и английском.

Как грамотно реализовать переключение языков и перевод ответа сервера?

Comment: АПИ должно уметь возвращать ответ на разных языках, иначе локализация сильно затруднена или невозможна. Хотя зависит от АПИ, у вас что за данные в ответе?

Comment: погодное api. в том то и дело, что единственные адекватные и бесплатные погодные api англоязычные.

Comment: Это дело сервера, и фронту тут ничего не поделать, рекомендую внимательнее поизучать api, потому что много погодных api имеет полноценную локализацию, например https://www.openweathermap.org везде имеет url параметр lang, по которому возвращает локализированные данные

Comment: я как раз с ним работаю. но он переводит не все, а только пару слов

Answer (score 1):

## React Intl

Пожалуйста, посмотрите эту статью: [React Intl: интернационализация React-приложений](https://habr.com/ru/company/macloud/blog/564824/).

### Гид по библиотеке

#### Установка

`npm i react-intl`

#### Пример использования

##### Структура проекта

```
├── src
│    ├── app
│    │    └── index.js
│    ├── i18n
          ├── locales.js
│    │    └── messages.js
...
```

##### Использование

`src/app/index.js`

```
import { IntlProvider, FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import { LOCALES } from '../i18n/locales.js';

function App() {
    const locale = LOCALES.ENGLISH
    return ( 
        <IntlProvider
            messages={messages[locale]}
            locale={locale}
            defaultLocale={LOCALES.ENGLISH}
        >
            <FormattedMessage id='example_key' />
        </IntlProvider>
    );
}
```

`src/i18n/locales.js`

```
export const LOCALES = {
  ENGLISH: 'en-US',
  RUSSIAN: 'ru-RU',
  ... (Другие языки)
}
```

`src/i18n/messages.js`

```
import { LOCALES } from './locales'

export const messages = {
  [LOCALES.ENGLISH]: {
    example_key: 'Hello, World!'
  },
  [LOCALES.RUSSIAN]: {
    example_key: 'Привет, Мир!'
  },
  ... (Другие языки)
}
```

#### Примечание

- Вам необходимо объявить переводы строк, чтобы их в дальнейшем использовать.
- Ключи в атрибуте `id` компонента `FormattedMessage` и сообщений `messages` файла `src/i18n/messages.js` должны совпадать.
- В сообщениях возможно использование переменных по типу `{n, number, ::currency/USD}`, где первый элемент (n) — это ключ (key), который используется для поиска соответствующих данных. Второй элемент (type) — это тип данных для преобразования, соответствующий определенной локации. Использование в компоненте: `<FormattedMessage id='price_display' values={{ n: 59.99 }} />`

Ссылка на документацию [React Intl](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/installation/).